# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined error with Firebase connection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a issue... The main idea of the getRoomInfo() function assigning the data in the document on the firebase to state with id but I'm stuck. I want to feed it from Firebase, it has a value in the document and when I give this value from outside, I want it to return given according to that document id in the program and assign these as state.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {
    Grid,
    Typography,
    Card,
    IconButton,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import Spotify from 'spotify-web-api-js';
import PlayArrowIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PlayArrow";
import PauseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Pause";
import SkipNextIcon from "@material-ui/icons/SkipNext";
import SkipPreviousIcon from '@material-ui/icons/SkipPrevious';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {GridItem, Heading, Divider} from '@chakra-ui/react';



const spotifyWebApi = new Spotify();

//const Player = props =>
class Player extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    const params = this.getHashParams(); 
    this.state = {
      logeedIn : params.access_token ? true : false,
      currentStatus: false,
      rooms: {
      roomAdminMail: "",
      roomName: "",
      roomInfo: ""
      }, 
      nowPlaying: {
        artist_name : 'Not Checked',
        song_name: 'Not Checked',
        image: ''
      }
    }
    this.getRoomCollection = this.getRoomCollection.bind(this);
    this.getNowPlaying = this.getNowPlaying.bind(this);
    this.getRoomInfo = this.getRoomInfo.bind(this);
    
    if(params.access_token){
      spotifyWebApi.setAccessToken(params.access_token);
    }
   
  }

  getRoomInfo = () => {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection('rooms').doc("H5H2XjdwCyrsAboQeRxT").get().then(
      function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          this.setState({
            rooms: {
              roomAdminMail: doc.data().roomAdminMail,
              roomName: doc.data().roomName,
              roomInfo: doc.data().roomName
            }
          })
          console.log("Document data: " + doc.data().roomAdminMail + "name " + doc.data().roomName + this.state.rooms.roomAdminMail);
        } else {
           console.log("No such document!");
        }
      }
      
    )
  }


  getRoomCollection = () => {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection("rooms").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        this.setState(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          rooms: {
          roomAdminMail: doc.data().roomAdminMail,
          roomName: doc.data().roomName,
          roomInfo: doc.data().roomInfo
          }
        })));
      })
     

    }


  getHashParams() {
   var hashParams = {};
   var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
       q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
   while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
      hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
   }
   return hashParams;
 }

 getNowPlaying = () =>{
  spotifyWebApi.getMyCurrentPlayingTrack()
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      nowPlaying: {
        artist_name: response.item.artists[0].name,
        song_name: response.item.name,
        image: response.item.album.images[0].url
      }
    })
  })
   
}



componentDidMount(){
    this.getNowPlaying();
    this.getRoomInfo();
    
    
}

  
    render() {
      var styles = {
        padding: "10px",
        margin: "10px"
      };
      
      return (
        <GridItem
        colStart={[1, null, null, 2, null, null]}
        colSpan={[3, null, null, 1, null, null]}
        p={6}
      >
         <Heading as="h4" size="md" style = {{
             padding: "10px",
             margin: "10px",
             alignItems: "center",
             }}>
           <a href='http://localhost:8888'>
           <button>Login With Spotify</button>
             </a>
          </Heading>
          <Divider orientation="horizontal" />
        
        <Typography component="h5" variant="h5" style = {styles}>
            Room Admin: {this.state.rooms.roomAdminMail}
        </Typography>

  
       
      <Card item align="center" style = {styles}>
        <Grid container alignItems="center">
          <Grid item align="center" xs={12} className="now-playing__img">
          <img src={this.state.nowPlaying.image} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item align="center" xs={8}>
          <Typography item align="center" component="h5" variant="h5">
          {this.state.nowPlaying.song_name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography item align="center" color="textSecondary" variant="subtitle1">
              {this.state.nowPlaying.artist_name}
            </Typography>
            <div>
            <IconButton
                onClick={() => { spotifyWebApi.skipToPrevious();
                    {this.getNowPlaying()}
                }}
              >
                <SkipPreviousIcon /> 
              </IconButton>
            <IconButton
                onClick={() => { spotifyWebApi.play();
                    {this.getNowPlaying()}
                }}
              >
                <PlayArrowIcon /> 
              </IconButton>
               
            <IconButton
                onClick={() => { spotifyWebApi.pause();
                    {this.getNowPlaying()}
                }}
              >
                <PauseIcon /> 
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton onClick={() => spotifyWebApi.skipToNext()}>
                {this.getNowPlaying()}
                <SkipNextIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>

          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        
      </Card>
      </GridItem>

 
  );
}
}

export default Player;
```

Comment: To preserve `this` you should use arrow function inside `getRoomInfo` as you do elswhere

Comment: Thank you, but can you show me how I can do this?

Comment: Replace `then(function(doc) {..})` with `then((doc)=> {..})` Same as `.then((response) => {` that you already have in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solve my problem. I'm grateful you.

Comment: No worries, glad to help!